# How to get the content of an XML node using XPath and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, nodes

I have code like this:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)
@doc.xpath(query).each do |html|

  puts html # how get content of a node
end
```

How do I get the content of the node instead of something like this:

```
<li class="stat">
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the Synopsis example in the [README file](http://nokogiri.org/README_rdoc.html) for Nokogiri showing one way to do it using CSS, XPath or a hybrid:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

# Get a Nokogiri::HTML:Document for the page we’re interested in...

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.google.com/search?q=tenderlove'))

# Do funky things with it using Nokogiri::XML::Node methods...

####
# Search for nodes by css
doc.css('h3.r a.l').each do |link|
  puts link.content
end

####
# Search for nodes by xpath
doc.xpath('//h3/a[@class="l"]').each do |link|
  puts link.content
end

####
# Or mix and match.
doc.search('h3.r a.l', '//h3/a[@class="l"]').each do |link|
  puts link.content
end
```

Answer (score 5):

See [`html.content`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#content-instance_method) or `html.text`.

See the [Node documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) for more information.

Comment: The link is dead, maybe you want to point at : http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node now ?

Comment: I fixed the broken link. When linking to off-site documentation, it's really important to include a summary of the most important point you're making, along with the reference and attribution to the document. Links rot then break and when they do they're useless to anyone.